# Spring security configure issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, openapi

Here is my configuration in security and the problem is all the requests such as `/v3/api-docs` will be redirected to `/login` or `/register`.I don't know why and Please help.

```
package reg.example.confgure;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

import reg.example.model.User;
import reg.example.service.UserRepositoryUserDetailService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity 
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { 

    @Autowired
    private UserRepositoryUserDetailService userDetailsService; 

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v3/api-docs",
                "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui",
                "/swagger-resources",
                "/swagger-resources/configuration/security",
                "/swagger-ui.html");
    }

    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(User.PASSWORD_ENCODER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
        http
            // 关闭csrf防护
            .csrf().disable()
            .headers().frameOptions().disable()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/v3/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui",
                    "/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources/configuration/security",
                    "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login","/register").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
    


}
```

```
package reg.example.confgure;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/register").setViewName("register");
    }
    


}
```

Comment: could it "possibly" be because of `.anyRequest().authenticated()`